# Use of python script instead of VBA in Excel

Tags: python, excel

I am new to python and its workings.
I have an excel spreadsheet which was got using some VBA's.
Now I want to invoke Python to do some of the jobs...
My question then is: How can I use python script instead of VBA in an excel spreadsheet?
An example of such will be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question with correct tags.

Comment: I doubt about MS Excel, but in OpenOffice / LibreOffice, you definitely can use Python for scripting.

Comment: A simple google search brought me to a [this site](http://www.python-excel.org/) specifically talking about Excel and Python. It also includes [this pdf](http://python-excel.googlegroups.com/web/python-excel.pdf?gda=_Mjv50IAAAAK26IHZlH6sZ8eLgsep540Mb62vrQuKzul1ptdke7-KtXEtWX7y7b6ByPnawQ3OxpV4u3aa4iAIyYQIqbG9naPgh6o8ccLBvP6Chud5KMzIQ) giving a deep explanation of the packages and contains examples.

Answer (score 1):

Resolver One, or Dirigible:

http://www.resolversystems.com/products/

Comment: Hey, I work at Resolver, so I'm biased, but if you can bear to export from Excel, then both Resolver One or Dirigible will import data and cell formulae from Excel sheets (only .xls or cvs formats are currently supported, and we don't currently attempt to import VBA functions) Then you can script in Python to your heart's content, and use full Python expressions in cells (including calling functions you define, using classes, 3rd party modules, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I've always done the manipulation of Excel spreadsheets and Word documents with standalone scripts which use COM objects to manipulate the documents. I've never come across a good use case for putting Python into a spreadsheet in place of VBA.